# image width and height is not getting correctly after scale

Tags: android, layout, scale

I scaled the image using

```
 iv.setScaleX(2);
 iv.setScaleY(2);
```

but after that,  I measure the width and height. but I am getting the initial value only.

```
iv.getWidth();
iv.getHeight();
```

Comment: setScaleX() and setScaleY() it will not change the view dimension. It will scale with respect to view center

Comment: Is it possible to get the final dimensions?

Comment: iv.getWidth();
iv.getHeight(); gives final dimension

Comment: I already checked. Not getting

Comment: I gave a code snippet please try

Comment: did you find the solution

Comment: yes. I got it. u need?

Answer (score 2):

setScale(int value). this function is used for zooming a view, not changing it's original width and height

Comment: Is it possible to get the final width and height after the operation?

Comment: what do you want ? zoom a view or increase the width and height to double of original width and height ?

Comment: if you want to double width and height, you can do that

`view.setwidth(2*view.getWidth());`

Comment: Actually I zoom the image manually. I need the dimensions after the operation

Comment: Zooming does not change the original width and height, width and height remains constant during zoming

Comment: Is there is any way to get the final dimensions

Comment: Try getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight().

Answer (score 1):

After matrix operation, you will not get the changed width and height. If you don't know the amount of scale you can get it using

```
   float scaleX = iv.getScaleX();
   float scaleY = iv.getScaleY();
```

and the final width and height after scale

```
  float finalWidth = iv.getWidth() * scaleX;
  float finalHeight = iv.getHeight() * scaleY;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap bit = ((BitmapDrawable)iv.getBackground()).getBitmap();
int width = bit.getWidth();
int height = bit.getHeight();
```

Comment: sorry
i set the image as background and tried this but no use. still getting same value.

Answer (score 0):

1. In fact, scale function just zoom image without change origin width / height size, thus **you can't get new size from getWidth() / getHeight()**
2. Don't use **width * scale** or **height * scale**, because in android, you need width height in integer type and this way will return float value, then you convert it to int? -> wrong ratio

**My solution:**

You can [getHitRect(rect)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getHitRect(android.graphics.Rect)) function, it return rectangle bound around this view, it's useful function in custom view

```
val rect = Rect()
getHitRect(rect)
val scaleWidth = rect.width()
val scaleHeight = rect.height()
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this instead

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

or

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

Comment: I don't want to fit the image to the view. Need to get the dimensions after applying zoom.